# WP Page Options CSS Editor

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I'm working in a simple plugin for my workplace, which styles the tiny mce area with custom buttons, fonts and styles. The plugin creates a Page Options with text fields, checkboxes and others. Most of the plugin functionality is complete, with the exception of the custom CSS.

To establish a context, my tiny mce function requires a path to the custom stylesheet:

```
function tiny_mce($in){

    $in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/build/styles/tiny-mce-editor.css";
    return $in;

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'tiny_mce' );
```

Is a very simple function! What I want to achieve is provide a blank CSS fie in my plugin folder. At the same time, include a text field in the page options to edit this CSS file. I will then link this CSS file into my tiny_mce function. That way, the user can edit the file form the back end, save changes and the styles will appear in the editor.

Hope I was clear enough. I'm open to different suggestions (save the contents of a textfield in CSS format in a $variable and then just include the variable in the function instead of the CSS url path?)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is my current code and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong -- I'm still in the process of learning this (I have never worked with writing files but it starting to make sense):

```
function tiny_mce($in){
    global $mce_options;

    $single_custom_css = $mce_options['textarea'];
    $file =  (dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/includes/css/editor-style.css' );
    file_put_contents($file, $single_custom_css);

    $in['content_css'] = $file;
    return $in;

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'tiny_mce' );
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What exactly is a problem of saving contents of text field into this mentioned file and the loading contents of file into a text field when user goes to a settings page?

Comment: What did you tried so far? What's the issue?

Comment: @Flyer I'm not familiar storing the data in the .css file through a text field. I'm having trouble finding instructions on how to do it! Sorry if i was not clear enough, will update question.

Comment: same as with any file. Read through: [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php), [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), [fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

Comment: @Flyer I updated my answer but I still have no luck writing the contents into the file. Is this a permission issue? I'm certain all my permissions are set correctly and I'm working locally -- Ideally I wouldn't have to deal with permissions as this is a plugin to install in different sites, different hostings, etc.

Comment: @mmarquez try `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` instead of `(dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) )`. Also, write contents to file only when settings are saved on your settings page. Read that file when options are loaded on that settings page. I doubt it's file permissions. If you're able to update/install plugins/themes from wp-admin automatically (it's not asking you for ftp access) then your permissions are fine.

Comment: Thank you @Flyer, this is the correct answer. You've helped me a lot in the last couple of days!!

Comment: @mmarquez You're welcome ;)